# Change remote host IP address without losing control (Linux)

Tags: linux, ip, routing

How can I change a remote host *primary* IP address without getting disconnected **at all** (without being in a "no IP addr" state).

The matter is poorly discussed on Internet (according to my research). The best resource [I found](http://madduck.net/blog/2006.10.20%3afreeing-the-primary-ip-address/) is a little bit tricky.

EXAMPLE : change 10.0.0.11/24 to 10.0.0.15/24

```
1. ssh root@10.0.0.11
2. ip addr add 10.0.0.15/24 dev eth0 
3. logout

4. ssh root@10.0.0.15
5. ip addr del 10.0.0.11/24 dev eth0
```

*Problem:* The last command removes both IP addresses and the connection is lost because 10.0.0.11 is primary, and it removes its secondary addresses (to which 10.0.0.15 belongs) when deleted.

I know I could "cheat" by adding 10.0.0.11/**25** (instead of **24**). However, I think it is theoretically possible to do this properly.

What do you think?

Comment: it is no cheat if you use /32 mask...

Comment: but it would not work because a /32 cannot communicate with anything but itself...

Comment: ok, but /25 will also not work than.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set the `promote_secondaries` option on the interface, or on all interfaces:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/promote_secondaries
```

or

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.promote_secondaries=1
```

Change `eth0` to `all` to have it work on all interfaces.

This option has been in [since 2.6.12](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=commitdiff;h=8f937c6099858eee15fae14009dcbd05177fa91d).

I tested this with a dummy interface and it worked there.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! See the [original commit](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=8f937c6099858eee15fae14009dcbd05177fa91d).

Comment: Please note that this option is available **since 2.6.12**, so *before* 2.6.16.

Comment: Is there an IPv6 equivalent to this?

Answer (score 0):

So procedure is I change it in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-en2xxx`
and then run either this command (as root):

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/promote_secondaries
```

or

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.promote_secondaries=1
```

Currently, my CentOS server is in DHCP and I want to remotely give it a static IP without loosing connection.